# Docker-compose for Neo4j and Python, connection error

Tags: python, docker-compose, neo4j

I use docker-compose to bundle a Flask python app which interacts with a Neo4j database. The two docker images work fine separately, but I cannot connect the two with docker-compose, and when I launch the `sudo docker-compose up --build` command, I have the following error when the python process start running :

```
Building backend-service
Sending build context to Docker daemon  39.87MB
Step 1/6 : FROM continuumio/miniconda3
 ---> 67414e5844b6
Step 2/6 : COPY . /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e72c927b5bc8
Step 3/6 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ab864f3a6042
Step 4/6 : RUN conda env create -f environment.yml
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4b36888dd60b
Step 5/6 : SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "VisualQueries", "/bin/bash", "-c"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d25cbc823371
Step 6/6 : RUN python "VisualQueries.py"
 ---> Running in 23a473684c00
ERROR conda.cli.main_run:execute(33): Subprocess for 'conda run ['/bin/bash', '-c', 'python "VisualQueries.py"']' command failed.  (See above for error)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "VisualQueries.py", line 28, in <module>
    neo4j_connector = Neo4jDirectConnector()
  File "/usr/src/app/hig/Neo4jDirectConnector.py", line 104, in __init__
    self.find_node_labels()
  File "/usr/src/app/hig/Neo4jDirectConnector.py", line 139, in find_node_labels
    labels = self.query("""CALL db.labels()""")
  File "/usr/src/app/hig/Neo4jDirectConnector.py", line 123, in query
    assert self.driver is not None, "Driver not initialized!"
AssertionError: Driver not initialized!

Failed to create the driver: Cannot resolve address neo4j:7687

The command 'conda run -n VisualQueries /bin/bash -c python "VisualQueries.py"' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Service 'backend-service' failed to build : Build failed
```

It seems I cannot initiate the connection to the Neo4j database from the python process. I use the following commands, neo4j being the name of the docker service of the Neo4j database :

```
uri = "bolt://neo4j:7687"
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=("neo4j", "neo4j"))
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml file :

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  neo4j:
    image: neo4j:4.4.2-community
    hostname: neo4j
    container_name: neo4j
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"
      - "7687:7687"
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/neo4j/plugins/:/plugins
    environment:
      - NEO4J_dbms_memory_pagecache_size=1G
      - NEO4J_dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=1G
      - NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_max__size=1G
      - NEO4J_AUTH=none
    networks:
      - visual-queries

  backend-service:
      build: ./HistorIGraph
      volumes:
        - ./HistorIGraph:/usr/src/app
      ports:
        - "10090:10090"
      depends_on:
        - neo4j
      networks:
        - visual-queries 

networks:
  visual-queries:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `links` configuration:

```
backend-service:
      build: ./HistorIGraph
      volumes:
        - ./HistorIGraph:/usr/src/app
      ports:
        - "10090:10090"
       depends_on:
         - neo4j
       networks:
         - visual-queries
       links:
        - neo4j
```

Edit:

You are probably correct, Neo4j database has not started at that point yet probably.
First run the Neo4j container with:

```
docker-compose up --build neo4j
```

Wait 30 seconds or so so that Neo4j is up and running and then run:

```
docker-compose up --build backend-service
```

Now the backend service should be able to connect to Neo4j

Comment: I added the links configuration but I get the same error. It looks like the neo4j database is not starting, or the connection is not working